# Ayuda para elegir un chart o grafica de datos

Tags: php, javascript

Quisiera que me aconsejaran a partir de su experiencia para representar datos mediante gráficos o charts, lo que sucede es que tengo una base de datos en sql server, esta contiene mas de 30.000 registros, al realizar ciertas consultas, esta me pueden dar como resultado 10.000 o mas registros. El problema surge cuando tengo que representar estos datos en una gráfica, he usado chart js, pero al momento de mostrar los gráficos se pone muy lento por la cantidad de datos, también he usado highcharts y va de maravilla, el problema es que no es open source y mi cliente no tiene como pagar la licencia, por ultimo también intente usar dygraphs, pero resulta que cuando las fechas son iguales, solo me muestra una y no todas las fechas como debería de ser.

Llegado a este punto, no se que otra opción utilizar, que sea open source y tenga la capacidad de representar una cantidad de datos considerable, me ayudarían de mucho si pudieran aconsejarme alguna otra librería para realizar este proceso.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con [amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/). Te da muchas opciones para ajustar los gráficos a tus necesidades. No es open source, y es un poco costosa, pero tienen una versión gratuita que incluye un pequeño enlace que dice "JS chart by amCharts".

[Aquí](https://www.amcharts.com/download/) puedes descargarla y [aquí](https://www.amcharts.com/licenses/javascript-charts-free-license/) puedes leer más sobre su licencia gratuita y determinar si en tu caso aplica.

Otra opción puede ser [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) y su [licencia](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/LICENSE).

Comment: pero se supone que en su pregunta original el OP esta indicando que su cliente no puede pagar una licencia, entonces esto como lo resuleve si dices que es costosa?

Comment: @shadow Como mencioné, tienen una versión gratuita. Lo único que piden a cambio es un pequeño enlace a su sitio.

Comment: @RockoDev Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, quisiera saber hasta que punto se puede hacer uso de esta versión gratuita? porque higcharts también tiene una versión gratuita, el problema con ellos es que solo se puede hacer uso de dicha licencia mientras el uso sea personal o a fines de aprendizaje, ya cuando se comercializa, así tenga los derechos de autor mencionados, toca que pagar una licencia para poder hacer uso

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo CHARTJS es una excelente librería para iniciarte en los gráficos te dejo un ejemplo aquí

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

El link de la librería es 
http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta alex, pero definitivamente no es una opción viable en cuanto a cantidad de datos se refiere, es muy lento cuando tiene que procesar una gran cantidad, hasta suele congelar la aplicación